# Regular Expression in model class in C#

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework

I want to disallowance only list special character ",',<,> in Model Class C#.

I use this following code, but it's not work.

```
[RegularExpression("^[^<>'\"]+$", ErrorMessage = "Special Character Don't allowance.")]
public string title { get; set; }
```

Please help me, thanks all so much.

Comment: you should give input example, what to allow and what not allow?

Comment: Also, if you want to have that error message in proper English, it would be "Special characters are not allowed."

Comment: for example
<"don't alow"> -> error

Answer (score -1):

Your model validation is doing the opposite of what you want, that is allowing `title` values containing **only** special characters and rejecting the ones without special characters.

Change the regular expression to

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\w\-. ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Special Characters are not allowed.")]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your regex is working exactly as you wanted.. try the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/MgEsNc/1)